# Cakephp textarea

Tags: php, html, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am using CakePHP 2.2.3. I have a contact form with a model without a table but with validation rules.

My problem is, how to tell CakePHP that the input type is textarea ? I could use `$this->Form->textarea()` but I've noticed that when I use it, it doesn't create the proper HTML to report validation errors back. If I use `$this->Form->input()` it just creates a normal input type text.

It should create something like:

```
<div class="input email required"><input name="data[Quote][email]" required="1" type="email" id="QuoteEmail"/></div>
```

but instead it creates something like:

```
<textarea name="data[Quote][company_description]" id="QuoteCompanyDescription"></textarea>
```

notice the absence of `<div class="input email required"></div>`, which I assume is the DOM element CakePHP uses to inject the validation error.

I would like to know what's the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I tend to use input() for all types and then specify in the options array..

```
$this->Form->input('company_description', array('type' => 'textarea'));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: Check the name of the field matches the one in the models validation.

Comment: It does, but how should I say in the Model that it is a textarea? I currently have only the notEmpty rule and a message for that rule.

Comment: You tell the field to be a `<textarea>` instead of an `<input>` in the view, with the code above, no need to add textarea into the validation.

Comment: Ok it's fixed and working. It was probably server-side cache. Thanks.

Comment: Did you created Form with model name? <?php echo $this->Form->create('Quote'); ?> ??

Answer (score 3):

Try following which also include class that you specified as an option

```
echo $this->Form->input('company_description', array('type' => 'textarea', 'escape' => false,'class' =>'input email required');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#automagic-form-elements

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $this->Form->input('comment', ['type' => 'textarea', 'label' => false, 'placeholder'=> 'Comment here', 'escape' => false,'class' =>'comment', 'rows' => '10', 'cols' => '20']); ?>
```

Creates a `textarea` with specified number of rows and cols, not just a standard textarea.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code. Just code is not an answer.